# gbm algorithm is taking too long until R-studio crash

Tags: r, r-caret, gbm

My data set has 9619 row and 46 column. I'm training it with gbm algorithm but R-studio keep working until it crash or ask me to restart the session. how can i make it faster or what i'm doing wrong ?

```
gbm.fit <- train(classe ~ . , method = "gbm"  , data = training ,  verbose = FALSE , 
trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv" , number = 5 ,  repeats = 5, search = "random" ))
```

Comment: what library are you using? have you looked at `h2o` ?

Comment: i'm using caret , i will try it